# What is the difference between these 2 counters?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

What is the difference between these two statements if they are inside an `always_ff @(posedge clk)` block?

```
if(~Intf.DataFull) begin
   rWrPageCntr <= rWrPageCntr - 1;
end
```

vs

```
rWrPageCntr <= rWrPageCntr - ~Intf.DataFull;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the following assumptions regarding signal bit widths, there is a big difference:

```
module tb;

bit DataFull, clk;
bit [2:0] rWrPageCntr;
bit [2:0] rWrPageCntr2;

always #5 clk++;

always_ff @(posedge clk)
    if(~DataFull) begin
        rWrPageCntr <= rWrPageCntr - 1;
    end

always_ff @(posedge clk)
        rWrPageCntr2 <= rWrPageCntr2 - ~DataFull;
           
always @(negedge clk) $display("full=%b %d %d", DataFull, rWrPageCntr, rWrPageCntr2);

initial begin
    DataFull = 1;
    #150;
    DataFull = 0;
    #150 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
full=1 0 2
full=1 0 4
full=1 0 6
full=1 0 0
full=1 0 2
full=1 0 4
full=1 0 6
full=1 0 0
full=1 0 2
full=1 0 4
full=1 0 6
full=1 0 0
full=1 0 2
full=1 0 4
full=0 0 6
full=0 7 7
full=0 6 0
full=0 5 1
full=0 4 2
full=0 3 3
full=0 2 4
full=0 1 5
full=0 0 6
full=0 7 7
full=0 6 0
full=0 5 1
full=0 4 2
full=0 3 3
full=0 2 4
```

The first example behaves as you'd expect, but the second example is more complicated.

In your second example, before the subtraction, `DataFull` will be extended to 3 bits, then it will be bitwise inverted, yielding 7 and 6.  When `DataFull`=0, `~DataFull`=7.  When `DataFull`=1, `~DataFull`=6.

Answer (score -1):

Besides functional differences, the example with the enable condition will allow a tool perform clock gating. The other example would require additional logic resulting in higher area and power consumption.